# Cloud Computing - Suggesting customers migrate to the cloud (IBM) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, ibm, cloud-storage, us20130205007

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON suggesting customer migrate to the Cloud** - This application from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com) seeks to patent the idea of...Suggesting customers use a cloud computer infrastructure...! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 2/8/2012** that discusses:

> - Measuring historical performance data, identifying recurring IT problem which could be mitigated with cloud computing infrastructure and generating customer reports identifying migration to the cloud

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO involves measuring cost or scope of the recurring IT problem.

**TITLE: Suggesting cloud migration**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A method for suggesting a customer use cloud computing… Measuring historical data, identifying recurring IT problems, determing cloud computing could solve the problem, and generating a report

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130205007 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130205007?dq=20130205007)
- **Application Number**: US 13/368,491
- **Assignee**: IBM
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 2/8/2012
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 2/4/2014
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130144978)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for suggesting migration to a cloud computing infrastructure, the method comprising the steps of:
>
> 1. at least one processor analyzing historical incident data of an information technology (IT) environment, the analysis indicating any problems occurring in the IT environment;
> 2. the at least one processor determining, based on the historical incident data, that a problem is recurring in the IT environment;
> 3. the at least one processor determining that the problem can be mitigated in the cloud computing infrastructure; and
> 4. the at least one processor generating a report particular to the IT environment, the report identifying a benefit of migrating the IT environment to the cloud computing infrastructure.

In English this means:

> A method for suggesting customers use cloud computing infrastructure, comprising:
>
> 1. Analyzing historical IT data and finding problems in the customer's IT environment;
> 2. Identifying recurring IT problem;
> 3. Determing problem can be mitigated in cloud computing infrastructure;
> 4. Generating a report showing the benefits of cloud computing infrastructure.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 2/8/2012

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is measuring cost or scope of the recurring IT problem.

---

**"Suggesting customers use cloud computing infrastructure from the Applicant from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Interestingly, the status of the application is now Abandoned. I wonder about what happened in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

This technology already existed and was a subject of a research paper in 2011 link below.

Research paper -- http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1105/1105.0149.pdf
Referencing a product that did this from 2010 --http://assets1.csc.com/cloud/downloads/PAAS_Solution_Brochure_V5.pdf

Comment: I don't see either reference analyzing actual incidences.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite the second link on page 2 states "CSC Cloud Adoption Assessment provides a business and process-centric analysis that identifies the right business processes and applications to target for cloud-enablement".  While this does not specifically say incidences it would be hard to imagine any good analysis of a business process or application that completely ignores incidences.

Comment: In a marketing brochure "analysis that identifies the right . . . for cloud enablement" could well just mean "we will compare what you do now to what we have to sell and recommend everything that overlaps". To read into it that analyzing incidents for the kinds of things that are more likely to go wrong or do more damage if not in the could is to take advantage of what we learned from the applicant. Hind sight.